# is it possible - to insert google AdSense at Flutter Web application?

Tags: flutter, adsense, flutter-web

I try to insert the next code(Google AdSense) at my site, but unsuccessful by now. The code is:

```
            <script type="text/javascript">var nend_params={"media":00000,"site":000000,"spot":000000,"type":1,"oriented":1};0</script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="https://js1.nend.net/js/nendAdLoader.js"></script>
```

1.For a while I tried a 'dart:js' with sentences like that

```
    js.context.callMethod(..
```

but, think its not worked, because we need to show advertising, not only execute javascript code..

2.next, I suppose that it can be a WebView (a webview, at the webapp..) and try to use next:

dependencies:
  webview_flutter: ^0.3.14
but it is fall with

*"Error: PlatformException(Unregistered factory, No factory registered for viewtype 'plugins.flutter.io/webview'"...*

May be someone heve a positive experiense or can give me any advice.

Comment: I have build www.droidbiz.in website using flutter web. I have applied for adsense but it is giving Valuable Inventory: No content error. have u faced this issue? how to get flutter website approved by AdSense?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you just need those scripts in your webpage you could try to include it in the `web/Index.html` page directly.

Otherwise you will have to to use `ui.platformViewRegistry.registerViewFactory` as shown here [PlatFormView example](https://github.com/flutter/flutter_web/blob/master/examples/html_platform_view/lib/main.dart). Following code would add a script element to your page.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:ui' as ui;
import 'dart:html';

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    ui.platformViewRegistry.registerViewFactory("add_script", (int viewId) {
      ScriptElement element = ScriptElement()
        ..src = "https://js1.nend.net/js/nendAdLoader.js"
        ..type = "text/javascript";
      return element;
    });
    return Center(
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          Directionality(
            textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
            child: SizedBox(
              width: 640,
              height: 360,
              child: HtmlElementView(viewType: 'add_script'),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

> Note: This code needs a hosting widget like a scaffold inside a MaterialApp or something similar. For the code inside the script try creating a similar widget with different viewtype string and use the `setInnerHtml` or similar methods.

But you should be aware that this element is added as a shadow dom element in your page. This [issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/40080#event-2632885209) discusses about this.

[image]

Comment: Yes, it was appear at html - source, thank you very much!
But , unfortunately, its was solution for a while until the 'flutter_web' was active. But now, we get only 'flutter'-branch, for 'web'-app too. And I try to use that solution and fault - we cannt use package 'dart:html' with 'flutter'. And its not understandable - how to make a 'viewtype' for 'HtmlElementView'.
May be it can be done like that (https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/13bd52bf9e25ea4aa1372821c9da37ac73b672b6/packages/flutter/test/widgets/html_element_view_test.dart) but I can not figure out how.

Comment: @alex89607 as of now only the IDE's will complain about `dart:html` but the compiler will work just fine when you are using flutter master channel. Please check [this wiki](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/wiki/Upgrading-from-package:flutter_web-to-the-Flutter-SDK) to migrate your existing flutter_web based project to new flutter based web project.

Comment: One more thing, if you dont mind. I have got a full Javascript code with help HtmlElementView, but its not starting to showing, I only see loaded script at debugging. You have wrote, that I need to 'creating a similar widget with different viewtype string' but how I can get the result javascript code from widget worked? I tried to debug context, but cant find result data in 'platform_view$.HtmlElementView1.new'. Should I create some kinda a controller at HtmlElementView1 for getting data or it have another way?

Comment: I am not sure if I understood your point. If you want to run the script then  you should do it perhaps in the `onload` event of the body or the some other tag. Otherwise as a callback to an event like a button click.

Comment: My question is because dont understand accurately how work widget  HtmlElementView with JS-code. When I transfer to HtmlElementView  JS code( "<script type="text/javascript" src="https://js1.nend...") I  doesnot get in answer graphical banner. Its only return bigger block of code. Which, as I suppose, need to exectute once more.

Comment: At the screen [debug screen](https://i.imgur.com/7Tmotzz.png) located the HtmlElementView and I tried to find out the code of nendAdLoader.js (for example). Then I tried to once more use HtmlElementView to get advertisement banner. But I cannot get JS String at context tree! May be, I need to use key for it purpose?

Comment: What is the expected output? Can you show an example!

Comment: I would like to see expected output  with advertisement banner or at least any error from remote ad-server. But now its only my own local errors only.

Comment: for it solvation I try to use library 'krux/postscribe' because one time I get error about problem of loading javascript. And I prepare next code for starting that library (https://i.imgur.com/o6gBr0f.png), I do it with help "ui.platformViewRegistry.registerViewFactory" and completed code looks very good but all the time I get another error: "Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined  nonymous>:1:1". I suppose, that problem at import code of library, but at  sources at looks like postscribe.js was successfully loaded. That is the code for making view: https://i.imgur.com/TSPeJZR.png

Comment: Does adsense allow firebase hosting url?