# Is there a plugin or a way to show ads in Flutter Website?

Tags: flutter, admob, flutter-web

I want to show banner, rewarded and interstitial Ads on my website which is built with **Flutter Web**. It is easy to show Ads for **Flutter Android** (I have used `admob_flutter` plugin for that) but I could not find a way to show Ads for **Flutter Web**. I prefer **Adsense** but any other Ads network are OK for me. Do you have any suggestions to show Ads for **Flutter Web**?

Comment: Present your code that you have already tried to reach a solution?

Comment: @Gander Hi, I just tried to use `admob_flutter` plugin but I have noticed that it is useless for **Flutter Web**. Therefore, it is irrelevant to present these codes here. I welcome any suggestions or ways to show ads using any ads network.

Comment: You can use adsense instead, just check if app is running on phone use app package otherwise you can use adsense check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57909791/is-it-possible-to-insert-google-adsense-at-flutter-web-application

Answer (score 0):

firebase_admob is now deprecated, and google_mobile_ads is currently in use, but both do not support flutter web. However, you may use ads posted to websites using Google Adsense.

You can create an empty web page, add ads, and embed the flutter app into the HTML page.

Please review following links:

[Google Adsense](https://www.quicksprout.com/how-to-add-adsense-to-your-website/)

[Embed the flutter App in the website](https://www.quicksprout.com/how-to-add-adsense-to-your-website/)